# Morris.Line graph x and y axis label are not being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, axis, morris.js

I have a morris double line graph like this:

```
var lineGraph = Morris.Area({
    element: 'graph_line',
    xkey: 'Date',
    ykeys: ['Sales', 'Revenue'],
    labels: ['Sales','Revenue'],
    fillOpacity: '0.7',
    gridTextFamily: 'mtsRegular',
    hideHover: 'auto',
    lineWidth: '1px',
    lineColors: ['#076178','#1ecee8'],
    pointFillColors: ['#fff'],
    pointStrokeColors: ['#012e42'],
    data: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.LineGraph)],
    resize: true
});
```

And once the graph is rendered, it's missing the x and y axis labels... It looks like following:

[image]

What am I missing out here? Can someone help me out?

@Mohamed  here is the content of ViewBag.LineGraph:

```
{ Date: '2018-08-06', Sales: 1, Revenue: 9.75 },
{ Date: '2018-08-08', Sales: 1, Revenue: 21.03 },
{ Date: '2018-08-09', Sales: 1, Revenue: 4.75 },
{ Date: '2018-08-12', Sales: 1, Revenue: 27.66 },
{ Date: '2018-08-13', Sales: 3, Revenue: 63.33 },
{ Date: '2018-08-16', Sales: 2, Revenue: 192.29 },
{ Date: '2018-08-18', Sales: 2, Revenue: 47.37 },
{ Date: '2018-08-19', Sales: 1, Revenue: 28.94 },
{ Date: '2018-08-20', Sales: 1, Revenue: 66.09 },
{ Date: '2018-08-21', Sales: 1, Revenue: 24.73 },
{ Date: '2018-08-22', Sales: 4, Revenue: 93.53 },
{ Date: '2018-08-23', Sales: 1, Revenue: 27.59 },
{ Date: '2018-08-25', Sales: 2, Revenue: 142.52 },
{ Date: '2018-08-26', Sales: 1, Revenue: 24.77 },
{ Date: '2018-08-27', Sales: 3, Revenue: 69.79 },
{ Date: '2018-08-29', Sales: 2, Revenue: 67.63 },
{ Date: '2018-08-30', Sales: 1, Revenue: 15.3 },
{ Date: '2018-09-01', Sales: 1, Revenue: 73.69 },
{ Date: '2018-09-02', Sales: 4, Revenue: 270.38 },
{ Date: '2018-09-03', Sales: 2, Revenue: 50.07 }
```

Comment: With the `xkey: 'Date'`, you're telling the charts to find a key named Date in every value of your results. Are you returning one?

Comment: @MuhammadOsama yes as you can see from the hovered value on the picture that i've shown... see "2018-08-12" ?

Comment: It will be more helpful if you post the real object here instead of `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.LineGraph)` by viewing page source

Comment: @MuhammadOsama okay one sec i will post the content of that ..

Comment: @MuhammadOsama posted it, can you take a look ?

Comment: Check out my answer

Comment: You seem to have a modified Morris CSS. Can you post it too?

Comment: Your can visit it. Its an online CDN from morris.js official [web](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/)

Comment: @MuhammadOsama I will try replacing the scripts and css to see if it will work...

Comment: Be sure to include `raphael.min.js` as well

Comment: If you have `gridTextColor` set to `'white'` for example, this will hide the axis if your background is white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fine for me?

```js
var lineGraph = Morris.Area({
                element: 'graph_line',
                xkey: 'Date',
                ykeys: ['Sales', 'Revenue'],
                labels: ['Sales','Revenue'],
                fillOpacity: '0.7',
                gridTextFamily: 'mtsRegular',
                hideHover: 'auto',
                lineWidth: '1px',
                lineColors: ['#076178','#1ecee8'],
                pointFillColors: ['#fff'],
                pointStrokeColors: ['#012e42'],
                data: [{ 'Date': '2018-08-06', Sales: 1, Revenue: 9.75},{ Date: '2018-08-08', Sales: 1, Revenue: 21.03},{ Date: '2018-08-09', Sales: 1, Revenue: 4.75},{ Date: '2018-08-12', Sales: 1, Revenue: 27.66},{ Date: '2018-08-13', Sales: 3, Revenue: 63.33},{ Date: '2018-08-16', Sales: 2, Revenue: 192.29},{ Date: '2018-08-18', Sales: 2, Revenue: 47.37},{ Date: '2018-08-19', Sales: 1, Revenue: 28.94},{ Date: '2018-08-20', Sales: 1, Revenue: 66.09},{ Date: '2018-08-21', Sales: 1, Revenue: 24.73},{ Date: '2018-08-22', Sales: 4, Revenue: 93.53},{ Date: '2018-08-23', Sales: 1, Revenue: 27.59},{ Date: '2018-08-25', Sales: 2, Revenue: 142.52},{ Date: '2018-08-26', Sales: 1, Revenue: 24.77},{ Date: '2018-08-27', Sales: 3, Revenue: 69.79},{ Date: '2018-08-29', Sales: 2, Revenue: 67.63},{ Date: '2018-08-30', Sales: 1, Revenue: 15.3},{ Date: '2018-09-01', Sales: 1, Revenue: 73.69},{ Date: '2018-09-02', Sales: 4, Revenue: 270.38},{ Date: '2018-09-03', Sales: 2, Revenue: 50.07}],
                resize: true

            });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>


<div id="graph_line" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: What's the catch ... Is everything same as the code I posted ? :D

Comment: no clue really... here it works.... on my page it renders without labels

Comment: Have you tried replacing all the the above stylesheets and scripts with online cdn mentioned in my solution?

Comment: Muhamed , it was the css issue in the end... Someone hid the x/y axis text labels below the graph.. it's fixed now :)